# Initiate jQuery function by using AngularJS custom directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my code I want to recall `$('.ams-items').slimScroll()` function

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $('.ams-items').slimScroll({
    alwaysVisible: true
  });
});
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question does not conform with the community's guidelines, and will soon be closed by a moderator. You should edit it appropriately if you expect to get any answers. Good questions usually include: **A desired outcome or result**, **What you have tried so far to solve your problem** and more.

Answer (score 1):

### How to Encapsulate jQuery code in a Custom Directive<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894969/angularjs-append-html-in-the-ng-repeat-element)</sup>

Any jQuery code that manipulates the DOM should be encapsulated in a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) so that it is executed when the AngularJS framework instantiates the element.

```
app.directive("mySlimScroll", function()
     return {
         link: postLink,
     };
     function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
         elem.slimScroll({
             alwaysVisible: true
         });
     }
});
```

#### Usage:

```
<div class="ams-items" my-slim-scroll>
</div>
```

To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)