# Angularjs - Chartjs formatting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I am new to AngularJS. I have created a horizontal bar chart by using Chart.js and HTML. Now I would like to add AngularJS so that the chart is dynamically shown on the page. Could some one guide me how to start? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var config = {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "Dataset 1",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(154,178,96,0.5)",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(154,178,96,1)",
          data: [10, 15, 5, 81, 55],
        }, {
          label: "Dataset 2",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(197,213,167,0.5)",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(197,213,167,1)",
          data: [90, 85, 95, 19, 45]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }]
        }
      }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: HTML Code:<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

Comment: Any example which can explain linking directives / templates and controller  in Angular js will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### How to Encapsulate jQuery code in a Custom Directive<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894969/angularjs-append-html-in-the-ng-repeat-element)</sup>

Any jQuery code that manipulates the DOM should be encapsulated in a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) so that it is executed when the AngularJS framework instantiates the element.

```
app.directive("myChartJs", function()
     var config = {
         //....
     };
     return {
         link: postLink,
     };
     function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
         var ctx = elem[0].getContext("2d");
         new Chart(ctx, config);
     }
});
```

#### Usage:

```
<canvas id="myChart" my-chart-js>
</canvas>
```

To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)